# How to scale and predict a single sample the right way

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

From a breast cancer dataset (5 features + 1 diagnosis column), I have trained and tested a logistic model on the standardized data (StandardScaler()). I import the model using Pickle:

```
log = pickle.load(open('./log.pkl', 'rb'))
```

and want to predict if a new sample belongs to class 0 (benign) or class 1 (malignant).

The test data below belongs to class 1 (I have tried with multiple samples from class 1, all results in the classification of belonging to 0):

```
radius = 11.41
texture = 10.82
perimeter = 73.34
area = 403.3
smoothness = 0.09373
```

to create the sample and get the prediction, I have tried the following:

```
temp = [radius, texture, perimeter, area, smoothness]
temp = np.array(temp).reshape((len(temp), 1))
scaler = StandardScaler()
temp = scaler.fit_transform(temp)

# print(log.predict(temp))   # results in: ValueError: X has 1 features per sample; expecting 5
print(log.predict(temp.T)) # results in: [0] which is wrong

# print(log.predict_proba(temp)) # results in: ValueError: X has 1 features per sample; expecting 5
print(log.predict_proba(temp.T)) # results in: [[9.99999972e-01 2.78352951e-08]] which does not seem right
```

I have also tried:

```
new_sample = np.array([radius, texture, perimeter, area, smoothness])
# scaled_sample = scaler.fit_transform(new_sample.reshape(1, -1)) # resulting array: array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
# scaled_sample = scaler.fit_transform(new_sample.reshape(1, -1).T) # same as below
scaled_sample = scaler.fit_transform(new_sample[:, np.newaxis])
print(log.predict(scaled_sample.T))  # results in [0] which is wrong 
print(log.predict_proba(scaled_sample.T)) # results in: [[9.99999972e-01 2.78352951e-08]] which differs from the predict_proba above, and seems off
```

How is the right way to do such a prediction?

Thanks,

Best wishes, Birgitte

Comment: Why do you say 0 as a predicted class is wrong? Perhaps the performance of the model is just that bad that predicts always 0? Are the two classes balanced?

Comment: Hi Márcio, 
The class distribution is ~55/45%, so I don't think it is an imbalance issue. Using 70/30% train/test sets, the model resulted in an accuracy of 0.959, precision of 0.963, recall of 0.972 and F1 of 0.972.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code may looks much more simpler according the scikit-learn documentation on [predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) function:

```
temp = np.array([[radius, texture, perimeter, area, smoothness]]) # use double brackets
scaler = StandardScaler()
print(log.predict(scaler.fit_transform(temp)))
```

This is a right way to using it. But this function can say nothing about the quality of the regressor's fitting.

Comment: Using your solution on multiple new class 1 samples (and also class 0) gives the expected results! thank you!